# Null Extra when sending intent from BroadCast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that detects wether the application is connected to Internet or not and sends an intent with a string extra. But I am getting a null Extra :

This is the BroadcastReceiver

```
          public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent().putExtra("cnx","yes"));
    }
    else{

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent().putExtra("cnx","no"));
    }
}
```

}

and this my Activity code :

```
           networkChangeReceiver=new NetworkChangeReceiver() {
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String val=intent.getStringExtra("cnx");
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(layoutLauncher, "Pas de connexion Internet!"+val, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
          /*  if (val.equals("internet")){
        isNetworkAvailable(false);
            }
            else{
                isNetworkAvailable(true);
            }*/
    }
};
```

and this is the register code

```
             private void registerNetworkBroadcast() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}
```

This is part of the manifest

```
          <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tn.formation.mdsoft.bulletinimmobilier">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <application.....

       <activity android:name=".ui.activities.LauncherActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".tools.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

The intent is meant for LauncherActivity.

**Edit**

The scenario was faulted anyway so I neglected its implementation but in such case, better verify the the keys.

Comment: Can you share your Androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: So you are passing data with key `cnx` and getting with `internet`. Ofcourse it is going to be null.

Comment: That's me messing up after several corrections, even with the correct key its still null

Comment: You're code will not work as expected on Nougat and above because Manifest declared BroadcastReceivers for connection events will not get fired as per the API doc. Then you override the onReceive method for the NetworkChangeReceiver registered manually in code, so you will always get a null extra because you're actually connectivity Receiver will not forward the intent containing 'Yes' or 'No'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am getting a null Extra

Android does not have an `"internet"` or `"cnx"` extra on that `Intent`. And, you are creating an endless loop.

1. The system sends out a `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcast.
2. You have two receivers registered for that broadcast, and both receive the broadcast, with no `"internet"` or `"cnx"` extra.
3. One receiver adds the `"cnx"` extra to the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` `Intent` and sends the broadcast.
4. You have two receivers registered for that broadcast, and both receive the broadcast, with the `"cnx"` extra.
5. One receiver re-adds the `"cnx"` extra to the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` `Intent` and sends the broadcast.
6. You have two receivers registered for that broadcast, and both receive the broadcast, with the `"cnx"` extra.
7. One receiver re-adds the `"cnx"` extra to the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` `Intent` and sends the broadcast.
8. Lather, rinse, repeat

First, do **not** use system broadcasts for communicating within a single process of an app. Use `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Second, do **not** send a broadcast with a system `Intent` action. At best, you screw up lots of other apps on the device. At worst, you crash, because the system prevents you from sending that broadcast.

And, [as Burhanuddin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220068/115145), you are not using the same key for your extra.

Comment: can you please explain this : `First, do not use system broadcasts for communicating within a single process of an app. Use LocalBroadcastManager.`. Why we should not be using it :).

Comment: I corrected the key yet nothing, How is it two receivers ? now am rceiving it from one activity and eeds to receive it from all the present activities, does it still count as a System Broadcast ?

Comment: @MeknessiHamida The event you are looking to receive in you BroadcastReceiver is a system dispatched event, meaning it isn't you app broadcasting it but the Android Operating System it. You have two receiver because you declared one in your manifest and one in your activity.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez: "Why we should not be using it" -- security, plus IPC overhead and performance.

Comment: @MeknessiHamida: It is a bit of a mess. Also you cannot register for `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` in the manifest on Android 7.0+.

Comment: Is removing it from the manifest and sending te information through another intent will make it more logical ? (ps :Hail the legend )

Comment: @MeknessiHamida: I do not really know what you are trying to accomplish here, and so I cannot really answer that. If your app is in the foreground, you do not need this broadcast. Just try your Internet operation, and if it fails, work with `ConnectivityManager` to see if there is a working network (that cannot access your site due to firewall/proxy/etc.) or not. If your interest is in the background, use `JobScheduler` and `setRequiredNetworkType()` to only have your job invoked when there is a working network connection.

Comment: The thing is I need to get a json file from the server as soon as the appliction is started and parse it and save it localy, so I need to test internet connection considering that the user might launch the application then remember to activate his connection (in this case I endup with empty screens), is it still correct ? or I am elaborating too much in a trivial  task ?

Comment: @MeknessiHamida: As I wrote, just try your Internet operation, and if it fails, work with `ConnectivityManager` to see if there is a working network (that cannot access your site due to firewall/proxy/etc.) or not. However, beyond that, you need to have some sort of useful UI for all three cases: when there is no network connection, when there is a network connection and you are loading the data, and when the data is loaded.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, I already start doing the necessary changes to the different scenarios I am gonna accept your answer so whoever fall for such trap will find some insight

Answer (score 1):

Your intent key is different 
Here you key is "cnx"

```
if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {

        context.sendBroadcast(intent.putExtra("cnx","yes"));
    }
    else{

        context.sendBroadcast(intent.putExtra("cnx","no"));
    }
```

Your are retriving with "internet" key here

```
 String val=intent.getStringExtra("internet");
```

Change it to:

```
String val=intent.getStringExtra("cnx");
```